# how can I get the next question by clicking on button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to modify this jQuery code so that, when I press the "next" button, then the next question should appear, but not by clicking on the radio button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>jQuery Get Selected Radio Button Value</title>
      <style>
        * {
          background-color: wheat;
          font-size: 40px;
          align-self: center;
        }
    
        .big {
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
        }
    
        #title {
          font-size: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%;
          color: tomato
        }
    
        div {
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
          text-align: center;
        }
        #next{
          float:right;
          margin-right: 20%;
          color:tomato  
        }
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#game,#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
    
          $('#hobbie input').on('change',function () {
            var x = $('#game,#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#game,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport  ').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
          })
          $('#movie input').change(function () {
            $('#game,#sport,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          })
    
          $('#game input').change(function () {
            $('#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#game#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          })
    
          $('#sport input').change(function () {
            $('#game,#movie,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          })
          
          // for button position
          jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 1.2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }
    $('#next').center();
        });
    
      </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <h1 id="title">Interest</h1>

  <div class="level1">
    <div id="hobbie">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="hobbie" value="movie">movie</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="hobbie" value="game">games</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="hobbie" value="sport">sports</input>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="level2">
    <div id="movie">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="movie" value="action">action</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="movie" value="adventure">adventure</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="movie" value="scifi">Sci-Fi</input>
    </div>

    <div id="game">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="game" value="gta">GTA</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="game" value="fpp">FPP</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="game" value="historic">Historic</input>
    </div>

    <div id="sport">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="sport" value="indoor">indoor</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="sport" value="outdoor">outdoor</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="sport" value="esport">esport</input>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="level3">
    <div id="action">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="action" value="matrix">the Matrix</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="action" value="terminator">Terminator</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="action" value="madmax">Mad Max</input>
    </div>
    <div id="adventure">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="adventure" value="jumanji">Jumanji</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="adventure" value="rings">Lord of the Rings</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="adventure" value="avatar">Avatar</input>
    </div>
    <div id="scifi">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="scifi" value="inception">Inception</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="scifi" value="prometheus">Prometheus</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="scifi" value="martian">The Martian</input>
    </div>

    <div id="gta">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="gta" value="gtav">GTA-V</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="gta" value="vice">Vice City</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="gta" value="san">San Andreas</input>
    </div>
    <div id="fpp">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="fpp" value="battle">Battlefield</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="fpp" value="cod">Call of Duty</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="fpp" value="pubg">PUBG</input>

    </div>
    <div id="historic">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="historic" value="witcher">The Witcher Hunter</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="historic" value="assasin">Assasins Creed</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="historic" value="dead">Red Dead Redemption</input>
    </div>


    <div id="indoor">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="indoor" value="ludo">ludo</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="indoor" value="carrom">carrom</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="indoor" value="cards">cards</input>
    </div>
    <div id="outdoor">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="outdoor" value="cricket">Cricket</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="outdoor" value="football">Football</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="outdoor" value="golf">Golf</input>
    </div>
    <div id="esport">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="esport" value="valorant">Valorant</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="esport" value="dota">Dota-2</input>
      <input type="radio" class="big" name="esport" value="cs">CS-GO</input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id='next'>Next</button>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your point in asking user for multiple actions (Select option & Click on the button) where he could get respective options just by selecting any of the option in your code.
Anyway you can try below code where you get next question by clicking on the next button. (This could be the example of hardcoding :P)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#game,#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            
            $('#hobbie input').on('change',function () {
                var x = $('#game,#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            })
            $('#movie input').change(function () {
                $('#game,#sport,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            })
            
            $('#game input').change(function () {
                $('#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#game#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            })
            
            $('#sport input').change(function () {
                $('#game,#movie,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
            })
            
          // for button position
          jQuery.fn.center = function () {
            this.css("position","absolute");
            this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 1.2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
            this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
            return this;
          }
          $('#next').center();
          $("#next").on('click', function(){
            var hobbieselected = $('input[name=hobbie]:checked').val();
            var movieselected = $('input[name=movie]:checked').val();
            var gameselected = $('input[name=game]:checked').val();
            var sportselected = $('input[name=sport]:checked').val();
            
            if(hobbieselected == 'movie'){
                $('#game,#sport,#gta,#fpp,#action,#adventure,#scifi#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#movie').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'game'){
                $('#movie,#sport,#gta,#fpp,#action,#adventure,#scifi#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#game').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'sport'){
                $('#movie,#game,#gta,#fpp,#action,#adventure,#scifi#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#sport').show();
            }
            if(hobbieselected == 'movie' && movieselected == 'action'){
                $('#game,#sport,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#action').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'movie' && movieselected == 'adventure'){
                $('#sport,#action,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#adventure').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'movie' && movieselected == 'scifi'){
                $('#sport,#action,#adventure,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#scifi').show();
            }
            if(hobbieselected == 'game' && gameselected == 'gta'){
                $('#sport,#adventure,#scifi,#action,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#gta').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'game' && gameselected == 'fpp'){
                $('#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#game#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#fpp').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'game' && gameselected == 'historic'){
                $('#movie,#sport,#genre,#action,#game#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#indoor,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#historic').show();
            }
            if(hobbieselected == 'sport' && sportselected == 'indoor'){
                $('#game,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#action,#outdoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#indoor').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'sport' && sportselected == 'outdoor'){
                $('#game,#movie,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#esport').hide();
                $('#outdoor').show();
            }
            else if(hobbieselected == 'sport' && sportselected == 'esport'){
                $('#game,#movie,#genre,#action,#adventure,#scifi,#gta,#fpp,#historic,#indoor,#outdoor').hide();
                $('#esport').show();
            }
          });
      });
  </script>
```